# Update value in domain and same should reflect in attribute field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, domains

I have a SDE GDB, where i have no. of domains created. we have created domain for state names, which is used by all feature classes to update their respective state name.

Now i have discovered that spelling / name of some of the states are not correct. if i correct these spellings or names in domain. will it reflect in the attribute of all feature classes or is there any other way forward?

There are many thousand records in the GDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry since the changes you perform in the geodatabase domain will be reflected in all feature classes which has fields using this domain.

For instance, you have a gdb domain called StatesNames. It is of coded values type and has a couple of code-value pairs:

```
TX - Texxas
CA - Callifornia
NY - New YYork
```

When users created features, they have chosen in the drop-down list of possible values (as they appear in the gdb domain). After you have fixed your typos, all the values are getting automatically updated in the feature classes that have fields using this domain.

```
TX - Texas
CA - California
NY - New York
```

Comment: Thanks dear Alex, But if we edit code also like, previously it was TXX-Texxas and now we edit it like Tx-Texas, will it will also be auto-update in the respective fields and feature classes.

Comment: Unfortunately not, what you will get then is "TXX" left in the field. What you will need to do then is to use some Python code to update the fields from "TXX" to "TX" according to your new code. Since you don't have that many states misspelled the whole process of codes updates will be painless.